# Change child component state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. I'm starting to think that I'm wrong but I used to think that you could make the same using Functional syntax or Class-Components syntax. 
Is there a way to change the state of a child component using Functional components?

I mean something like this...

```
_onChildClick = (key, childProps) => {
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please take the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). It's really good, and covers everything you need to know. And if it's been a few versions since you took it: retake it and familiarise yourself with all the new functionality.

Comment: First, a component can always only modify its own state, never the state of child components or others. Components communicate with their childs via ``props``. You can think of props as external state that is exposed to their parents. Props behave the same for class and functional components. Secondly, functional components could not have state until earlier this year. Now they can using the Hooks syntax, which allows them to have state the same way that class components do, but with a very much different syntax than class components.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const {useState}  = React;

function App(){
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <div>
    Current count: {count}<br/>
    <button onClick={()=>setCount(count-1)}>-</button>
    <button onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)}>+</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.5/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.5/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

No, a parent component cannot change the state of a child component. The parent can only pass props to its children. This is the same for both functional and class-based components.